# list of changed fields from ChangeSetEntry in ChangeSet?

Tags: entity-framework, ria

i want to log the changed fields in RIA, using LinqToEntitiesDomainService,

how to get list of changed fields from ChangeSetEntry in ChangeSet?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I am looking at doing something like this right now, but the `ChangeSetEntry` only shows me that there in fact was a change, and what the field values changed to, not what they were BEFORE the change.

Comment: i did it by taking unmodified entity and then comparing individual properties,

Comment: Melissa, you can. Check ChangeSetEntry.OriginalEntity Property.

Answer (score 1):

You can get exactly what you want with [ObjectStateEntry.GetModifiedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.getmodifiedproperties.aspx) Method.
(for example in SavingChanges handler of your domain ObjectContext)

Comment: Is this even in `DbContext`? I can't seem to find it